# Error when trying to add a shard set in Mongo db

Tags: mongodb, errors

I'm trying to add a shard set in mongos I got this error and . Kindly help.

```
mongos>db.runCommand( { addshard : " firstset/ip_1:port_1,ip_2:port_2,ip_3:port_3" } );

{
      "ok" : 0,
      "errmsg" : "failed listing   firstset/ip_1:port_1,ip_2:port_2,ip_3:port_3's databases{ ok: 0.0, errmsg: \"not authorized on admin to execute command {listDatabases : 1 }\" ,code : 13 } "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least the role of clusterManager to perform this action in 2.6 . If you are a dbadmin you can grantRole clusterManager to current user following this tutorial http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/assign-role-to-user/